# If the limit of the subtraction of two periodic function is ZERO when x goes to INFINITY, is these two functions equals to each other?

Tags: calculus, periodic-functions

If $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ are **periodic functions** such that
$$\lim_{x \to + \infty }(f-g)(x)=0$$
Prove $f=g$, or give a counter example.

By the way, please notice that the period of $f$ and $g$ may not be equal nor rational.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is there a point where you are getting stuck?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг $f-g$ is in general not periodic if the ratio of their periods is irrational

Answer (score 1):

The result is right. Here follows the proof:
Let $T_1,T_2$ be the period of $f$ and $g$.
Then for $\forall\ x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(f(x+nT_1)-g(x+nT_1)\right)=0,$$
so $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(x+nT_1);$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(f(x+nT_2)-g(x+nT_2)\right)=0,$$
so $g(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x+nT_2).$
Thus$$f(x)-g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(g(x+nT_1)-f(x+nT_2)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(g(x+nT_1+nT_2)-f(x+nT_1+nT_2)\right)=0.$$
So we get $$f=g.$$

Comment: So you get that $f=g$?